# Unable to create a column based on condition(Python)

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

So I have a dataset 'dd' of 40,000 rows which looks like this:

```
dd.head(21)
Out[64]: 
    MT  MTBR       Prd  QPA    RT Type   WH
0    3   539  24Months    1  'NA'   NR  188
1    3    51  24Months    4  'NA'   NR  188
2    3   112  24Months   10     6   RP  188
3    3   385  24Months    2     7   RP  188
4    3   206  24Months    1     8   RP  188
5    3   349  24Months   19  'NA'   NR  188
6    3   569  24Months   18  'NA'   NR  188
7    3    66  24Months   20     8   RP  188
8    3   181  24Months    9  'NA'   NR  188
9    3   149  24Months    2  'NA'   NR  188
10   3   131  24Months    8     7   RP  188
11   3   289  24Months   11     3   RP  188
12   3   392  24Months   13     2   RP  188
13   3   303  24Months    9  'NA'   NR  188
14   3   318  24Months    5     5   RP  188
15   3   103  24Months    9     6   RP  188
16   3   447  24Months    8     6   RP  188
17   3   600  24Months   19  'NA'   NR  188
18   3   258  24Months   12  'NA'   NR  188
19   3   164  24Months   13  'NA'   NR  188
20   3   589  24Months   11  'NA'   NR  188
```

I want to create another column **mean_v** in this dataset having the following conditions:

```
for q,m,w,rt,mt in zip(dd.QPA,dd.MT,dd.WH,dd.RT,dd.MTBR):
    if dd.Type=='NR':
        dd.mean_v = q*m*w*24 / (mt*1000)

    elif dd.Type=='RP':  
         dd.mean_v = q*m*w*rt / (mt*1000)
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. 
Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Would really appreciate it if somebody could help me rectify the error in my code. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What exactly is `dd` in this context?

Comment: You should upvote/accept answers: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Sure I will, I was out for a while.

Comment: @Dipayan - Hmmm, so the fastest solution does not work? Because it is approximatelly 10 times faster as accepted answer. I think `jez4(dd)`. Or there is some another problem? Thanks.

Comment: @jezrael thanks a lot for your help, if it were possible I would have upvoted your answer too, it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using either dd.RT or 24 if dd.RT is 'NA'. Hence, you can use following 2-line code creating a new column and using it for calculations:

```
dd['RTT'] = list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x != "'NA'" else 24, dd.RT.tolist()))
dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * dd.RTT) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)

print(dd)
```

Output:

```
    MT  MTBR       Prd  QPA    RT Type   WH  RTT    mean_v
0    3   539  24Months    1  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.025113
1    3    51  24Months    4  'NA'   NR  188   24  1.061647
2    3   112  24Months   10     6   RP  188    6  0.302143
3    3   385  24Months    2     7   RP  188    7  0.020509
4    3   206  24Months    1     8   RP  188    8  0.021903
5    3   349  24Months   19  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.736917
6    3   569  24Months   18  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.428204
7    3    66  24Months   20     8   RP  188    8  1.367273
8    3   181  24Months    9  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.673061
9    3   149  24Months    2  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.181691
10   3   131  24Months    8     7   RP  188    7  0.241099
11   3   289  24Months   11     3   RP  188    3  0.064401
12   3   392  24Months   13     2   RP  188    2  0.037408
13   3   303  24Months    9  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.402059
14   3   318  24Months    5     5   RP  188    5  0.044340
15   3   103  24Months    9     6   RP  188    6  0.295689
16   3   447  24Months    8     6   RP  188    6  0.060564
17   3   600  24Months   19  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.428640
18   3   258  24Months   12  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.629581
19   3   164  24Months   13  'NA'   NR  188   24  1.072976
20   3   589  24Months   11  'NA'   NR  188   24  0.252795
```

Another option is to use apply:

```
dd['RTT'] = dd.apply(lambda row: int(row.RT) if row.RT != "'NA'" else 24 , axis=1)
dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * dd.RTT) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this

Answer (score 3):

In pandas is the best avoid loops because slow, so better is use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
#first replace all numeric to NaN and then to 0
dd.RT = 
m1 = dd.Type=='NR'
m2 = dd.Type=='RP'

s =  dd.QPA *dd.MT * dd.WH
s1 = dd.MTBR * 1000 

s2 = s * 24 / s1
s3 = s * dd.RT / s1

dd['mean_v'] = np.select([m1, m2], [s2, s3], default=np.nan)
```

But if only `NR` and `RP` values in `Type` column use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
dd['mean_v'] = np.where(m1, s2, s3)
```

---

Loop version (very slow):

```
dd.RT = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(0)    
for i, x in dd.iterrows():
    if x['Type'] =='NR':
        dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] = x.QPA*x.MT*x.WH*24 / (x.MTBR*1000)
    elif x.Type=='RP':
        dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] =  x.QPA*x.MT*x.WH*x.RT / (x.MTBR*1000)
    else:
        dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] = np.nan
```

---

If always `RT` is `24` for `TYPE==NR`:

```
s = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(24)
dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * s) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)
```

---

```
print (dd)

    MT  MTBR       Prd  QPA   RT Type   WH    mean_v
0    3   539  24Months    1  0.0   NR  188  0.025113
1    3    51  24Months    4  0.0   NR  188  1.061647
2    3   112  24Months   10  6.0   RP  188  0.302143
3    3   385  24Months    2  7.0   RP  188  0.020509
4    3   206  24Months    1  8.0   RP  188  0.021903
5    3   349  24Months   19  0.0   NR  188  0.736917
6    3   569  24Months   18  0.0   NR  188  0.428204
7    3    66  24Months   20  8.0   RP  188  1.367273
8    3   181  24Months    9  0.0   NR  188  0.673061
9    3   149  24Months    2  0.0   NR  188  0.181691
10   3   131  24Months    8  7.0   RP  188  0.241099
11   3   289  24Months   11  3.0   RP  188  0.064401
12   3   392  24Months   13  2.0   RP  188  0.037408
13   3   303  24Months    9  0.0   NR  188  0.402059
14   3   318  24Months    5  5.0   RP  188  0.044340
15   3   103  24Months    9  6.0   RP  188  0.295689
16   3   447  24Months    8  6.0   RP  188  0.060564
17   3   600  24Months   19  0.0   NR  188  0.428640
18   3   258  24Months   12  0.0   NR  188  0.629581
19   3   164  24Months   13  0.0   NR  188  1.072976
20   3   589  24Months   11  0.0   NR  188  0.252795
```

**Timings**:

```
In [1]: %timeit jez1(dd)
14.1 ms ± 82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [2]: %timeit jez2(dd)
8.97 ms ± 32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [3]: %timeit jez3(dd)
25.1 s ± 769 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [4]: %timeit (jez4(dd))
2.63 ms ± 38.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit (rsno(dd))
24.6 ms ± 267 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [6]: %timeit (rsno1(dd))
1.62 s ± 20.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

---

```
dd = pd.concat([dd] * 2000, ignore_index=True)

#print (dd)

def jez1(dd):
    dd.RT = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
    m1 = dd.Type=='NR'
    m2 = dd.Type=='RP'
    s =  dd.QPA *dd.MT * dd.WH
    s1 = dd.MTBR * 1000 

    s2 = s * 24 / s1
    s3 = s * dd.RT / s1

    dd['mean_v'] = np.select([m1, m2], [s2, s3], default=np.nan)
    return dd

def jez2(dd):
    dd.RT = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(0)
    m1 = dd.Type=='NR'
    s =  dd.QPA *dd.MT * dd.WH
    s1 = dd.MTBR * 1000 

    s2 = s * 24 / s1
    s3 = s * dd.RT / s1

    dd['mean_v'] = np.where(m1, s2, s3) 
    return dd

def jez3(dd):
    dd.RT = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(0)    
    for i, x in dd.iterrows():
        if x['Type'] =='NR':
            dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] = x.QPA*x.MT*x.WH*24 / (x.MTBR*1000)
        elif x.Type=='RP':
            dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] =  x.QPA*x.MT*x.WH*x.RT / (x.MTBR*1000)
        else:
            dd.loc[i, 'mean_v'] = np.nan
    return dd


def jez4(dd):
    dd.RT = pd.to_numeric(dd.RT, errors='coerce').fillna(24)
    dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * dd.RT) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)
    return dd

def rsno(dd):
    dd['RTT'] = list(map(lambda x: int(x) if x != "'NA'" else 24, dd.RT.tolist()))
    dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * dd.RTT) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)
    return dd

def rsno1(dd):
    dd['RTT'] = dd.apply(lambda row: int(row.RT) if row.RT != "'NA'" else 24 , axis=1)
    dd['mean_v'] = (dd.QPA * dd.MT * dd.WH * dd.RTT) / (dd.MTBR * 1000)
    return dd
```

Comment: Very interesting and insightful. Can you also time my `apply` version (I just added to my answer).

Comment: @rsno sure, but need some time because offline, on phone only.

Comment: I am waiting to see how `df.apply` fares compared to other methods.

Comment: @rnso - sorry, added to answer. very slow, only `loop` version is slowier.

Comment: So 'map' is much faster than 'df.apply' for similar actions.